# A/B test for 1 email Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

Is it possible to use Email with A/B test content block inside ( build in email studio)   and use it in Journey Builder? or the only way is to use random split?

Comment: Is there any reasons why you don't want to use Random Split?

Comment: It will be harder to do reporting if you use just one email but it’s possible

Comment: I want to use one email ( A/B test is for content block with button ) not 2 separate emails that's why Random Split is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @zuzannamj if it is possible could you explain how to do it? I did a test but it's not working for me.

Comment: How do you determine who gets which content inside the email?

Comment: I've added simply A/B test block inside the email. So it's random.

Comment: Duplicating the same email with two different content blocks would do it. I recommend using Path Optimizer activity inside Journey Builder too, it will send the email to a percentage of the audience, pick a winner and send it to the remaining contacts.

Comment: thanks a lot! but my aim was to reduce numbers of emails and make it in one, but it's not possible in journey builder.